# Stored Procedure with WHERE .. IN array parameter

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to set a boolean on every entry in a table matching an array of row ids passed into a stored procedure. Help me crack the proper syntax to accomplish this? The following is as close as I've gotten.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tester (id_list bigint[])
AS
$$
UPDATE some_table
SET touched = true
WHERE id IN (unnest(id_list));
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

CALL tester(ARRAY[12, 34]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ANY` operator:

```
UPDATE some_table
  SET touched = true
WHERE id = ANY (id_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

a_horse_with_no_name's ANY answer is tidier, but I also found out adding a SELECT in front of the unnest function also works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tester (id_list bigint[])
AS
$$
UPDATE some_table
SET touched = true
WHERE id IN (SELECT unnest(id_list));
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```